# How to install armr5-none-eabi-g++ and associated toolchain?

Tags: debian, apt, cross-compilation

I'm tasked with adding a cross-compiler to an existing Docker image that contains multiple cross-tools.

From our existing Dockerfile, I see that `apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential` has the effect of installing `/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++` and its associated binaries/toolchain (sorry: my terminology may be lacking).

Similarly, `apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends crossbuild-essential-arm64` seems to have the effect of installing `/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++` and its associated binaries/toolchain.

**Is there an `apt-get install` command that will similarly install `armr5-none-eabi-g++` and its associated binaries/toolchain?**

Searching online and on the various Stack Exchanges, I see reference to installing `arm-none-eabi-g++`, but I assume that is something distinct from `armr5-none-eabi-g++`(?)
Even if the two are functionally equivalent, I'd prefer a solution that installs specifically `armr5-none-eabi-g++`.

The Dockerfile base image is `debian:10.3-slim`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Debian packages (corresponding to the ARM toolchain), you should install [`gcc-arm-none-eabi`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/gcc-arm-none-eabi) which provides C and C++ cross-compilers for 32-bit ARM, including Cortex-R processors:

```
apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc-arm-none-eabi
```

The compiler command for C++ will then be `arm-none-eabi-g++`.

If you need the STL, you should also install [`libstdc++-arm-none-eabi-newlib`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libstdc++-arm-none-eabi-newlib):

```
apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libstdc++-arm-none-eabi-newlib
```

`armr5-none-eabi-g++` is (was) available in the Xilinx SDK; the relevant SDK nowadays would appear to be Vitis. For a container image you’d probably be best off installing it using the full unified installer archive. (I haven’t tried this so I can’t confirm that the `armr5-none-eabi` is included in current versions.)

Comment: At the risk of exposing my ignorance: what is the difference between `armr5-none-eabi-g++` and `arm-none-eabi-g++`?

Comment: I don’t know for sure; they may be equivalent, but perhaps `armr5` is optimised for, or even explicitly targets, Cortex R5. See [the ARM options in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html) to see all the possible settings — notably, `-mtune` and `-mcpu`.